# Excel VBA MSXML2 DOMDocument bind to mapped data

Tags: xml, vba, excel, msxml

I have an Excel file with an xml schema mapped to selected tables and cells. What I want to do is build a data validation VBA script to inform the user if all fields comply with the xsd.

I've gone through the MSXML2 documentation but the only way I found to bind the newly created instance of DOMDocument is to load data from an xml file. What I am actually looking for is to bind it to the data which is already in the workbook and residing in the mapped cells.

Can anybody help and post a sample piece of code?

Highly appreciated!

Lukasz

Comment: What did you try? Which error/warning message did you take ?

Comment: "..... post a sample piece of code?" I do not think so the aim of the people in this web page is to send sample codes

Comment: XML documents are validated against the schema during parsing (either DOM or SAX). One way to achieve it is to save the current state of XML and validate it against schema from disk/memory. I am not sure if you can do it for already loaded and mapped XML document (I might be wrong).